# Set key dynamically using jBuilder Elasticsearch with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, jbuilder

I want to enable the user to search using different fields from my model, for instance, a different field than `name`:

```
json.set!(:match, name: @term)
```

Is there a way to supply a value (string) instead of `name:` on the line above?

Comment: please provide more details, this tiny bit of code doesn't' tell us much.  At least show your model definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I got your question, if you have instance vairable @key_value, it can be name or body or other attribute name. You could do the following:

```
json.set!(:match, @key_value => @term)
```

Comment: @queroga_vqz  No worries.